# Query to get list of views that use a certain field in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Does anybody know of a query from system tables or views to get a list of views that use a certain field in a SQL Server database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM
    sys.sql_modules m
    JOIN
    sys.views v ON m.object_id = v.object_id
WHERE
    m.definition LIKE '%MyTable%' --or '%MyField%'
```

INFORMATION_SCHEMA views and legacy syscomments are unreliable for large view definition (or any definition) because they have nvarchar(4000) fields. sys.sql_modules uses nvarchar(max).

They should not be used

[sys.sql_expression_dependencies](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345449.aspx)  may be an alternative but is more complex to use.